# using loc with upper()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to bring back all values that, in upper case, equal "EU". My solution below doesn't work. Does anybody know how I would do this?

```
companies_df.loc[(upper(companies_df["location"]) == 'EU')].head(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the `upper` function is not applied correctly to the `location` column. In pandas, you can use the `str` accessor to apply string methods to a column.

```py
companies_df.loc[companies_df["location"].str.upper() == 'EU'].head(10)
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks, Amira!